# FORMATDATE and format pattern to add year when using format pattern "M"

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, date, format

I have this code

`````
SET @START_DT = "2019-08-05T06:07:08.1230000-06:00"
SET @CHANGE_DATE = FORMATDATE(@START_DT),"M","","da-DK")````
`````

Which output format is:

> 5. august

I would like to add the year to it so the output would be

> 5. august 2019

I tried to add diferent format pattern from https://ampscript.guide/formatdate/
Like "**DD MMMM YYYY**" it works, but I don't like the "0" infront

Output

> 05 august 2019

I like the format Pattern "M" with the year in the end

Comment: You have to do the following `FORMATDATE(@START_DT,"D. MMMM YYYY","","da-DK")`

Comment: You are great Johannes! That worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To provide it as answer (even though i might not be worth it):

You have to do the following `FORMATDATE(@START_DT,"D. MMMM YYYY","","da-DK")`

You can set delimeters like you want in these format strings and also whitespaces and stuff like it.

It could be
`FORMATDATE(@START_DT,"D/ MMMM /YYYY","","da-DK")` when you would like to have

> 5/ august /2019

or

`FORMATDATE(@START_DT,"D - MMM - YYYY","","da-DK")` when you would like to have

> 5 - aug - 2019

Just try to experiment with it on cloudpages and you can easily see what you want. (Just make sure to insert those ampscript likes inside ampscript codeblocks or inline ampscript and inside an HTML area [not text])

Comment: Ah very useful. I didn't know what. Thanks!

Comment: From: “I don’t know if this is good enough for an answer” to +6 and accepted in 6 hours. Well done 